# Camunda returns null for businessProcess .getProcessInstance()

Tags: java, camunda

`BusinessProcess` object returns null value when i try to retrieve `ProcessInsance` Object.

My code is as follows

```
@Inject
 private BusinessProcess businessProcess;


ProcessInstance instance = businessProcess.getProcessInstance();
```

where `businessProcess` is not null. I want to read business key from this process instance like

```
String bizKey = businessProcess.getProcessInstance().getBusinessKey();
```

Comment: So that method getProcessInstance() returns null. Is that your method, or where is it coming from?

Comment: Post your complete class, please. Is it a human task or a service task?

Comment: These are camunda internal classes

Comment: Hey Albin I think that there is no running process instance, thats why getProcessInstance returns null.

Comment: Dear Zelldon, This was happened after i modified the BPMN, before that its working fine.

Comment: Please post your process model

Comment: Albin, if this happened after you modified the BPMN, then I suggest the process is failing on startup. Try rolling your changes back, verify it still works and make sure your process runs.

Comment: @Greg Harley : Yes its works when i revert my change.

Comment: This suggests the process is failing on startup.